# ios - provisioning profile issues

Tags: iphone, ios, profile, ios-provisioning

I recently re-installed my mac for a good spring clean and did a complete backup with Super Duper:-)

Now on the day I did the re-install Apple's servers had issues with signing certificates, which I didn't know and thought I was messing things up. So I deleted all of them from my account and thought to start over again.

I have them downloaded, but obviously they are not on my account anymore.

Now I have an update for an app in the app store and no matter what I try, I can't sign the app to make it ready for the upload. **Have I completely stuffed this and do I need to make a new app in iTunes Connect?**

PS I do not believe this question is under NDA - if it is I am happy to delete it, I have also posted this on the apple forum, but I am seem to get quicker answers here:-)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you do DON'T make a new App. This is simply a provisioning profile and signing certificate issue. Just go through the process of setting those up all again. And then make sure your Project knows to use the NEW ones and does not have references to old ones in Git or whatever source code control you use.

Comment: Cool thanks for that info. I got it fixed, ended up not being far enough into the process yet:-) but this is good to know:-)

Comment: Yup, didn't want you getting an itchy delete finger (one of my problems) and making a mistake that would be a REAL pain in the arse to get sorted.